# Something to know about socket and multithreading in java

Tags: java, sockets

I want to send a message to a `socket` on a gateway(client), and then wait for a message to recieve from a gateway.

While waiting, on other hand I again send a message from server `socket` to gateway which is client but on `accept()`(ServerSocket) method my connection blocks.

I was wondering is this because of the previous request which was waiting to recieve something by using `inputStream`. I used `threads` to maintain this and use `setReuseAddress()` to do this.

I am not posting a code right now as I just want to know is this logic is fine or is there any logic to handle multiple requests(messages) to be send from a `Server-Socket` to a client-Socket and I also dont want to `close` the socket because the `socket` has to be connected through out the application.

Comment: Must you use sockets?

Are you familiar with Java RMI?

Java RMi allows you to avoid this socket/port methodology. With a few things to look out for with regards to clients disconnecting.

Comment: yeah I have to use the sockets.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  It's sounds like there is a ServerSocket on both sides calling accept()?

Comment: ServerSocket is only on my side, because client side has been build by someone. so when client runs it connects to my server socket. and then i send order request to a client, on the bases of that order request it sends me back some message. now during this message passing process. I again send another order request but the connection blocks. I am not familiar with RMI. but i will surely go through with this too.

Answer (score 1):

On the client end, you use a [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) object to connect to a server which uses a **single** [ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html).  Once the connection is established you will have a Socket at both ends and you can use this Socket to Serversocket connection to send data in either direction. i.e. 
A single server socket is needed for new connections only.

See: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)